# Displaying differnet objects that belong to a User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, this is pretty simple (I think) but I still have a hard time wrapping my head around this. I have an app, where as a `User` that is signed in can create `Topics` and `Bookmarks` which are nested in the `topics`. A `User` can also `Like` a `bookmark` another user created.

On my `users/show.html.erb` I'm trying to make a list of all the `bookmarks` and `likes` a `user` has created. Both have `user_id`'s which I would assume that's how I could call them, I'm just retarded and need some help.

What would I put in my `user_controller` and my `user/show.html.erb` files?

Thanks for the help!

Here is my User.rb

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,   :confirmable

has_many :topics
has_many :bookmarks, dependent: :destroy
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy

#liked method takes a bookmark object and returns a like object if one    exists
def liked(bookmark)
likes.where(bookmark_id: bookmark.id).first
  end
end
```

Like.rb

```
    class Like < ActiveRecord::Base

    #considered a simple join table, that represents a relation between        two objects (user/bookmark)
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :bookmark
    end
```

Bookmark.rb

```
 class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :topic
belongs_to :user
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Do you have any code written? You need relations defined in your models, do you have those already?

Comment: Yeah, relations are already defined, but nothing yet for my user files. @Beartech

Comment: That's not clear, are you saying you don't have any relations written for your users? It would help if you post code you already have so someone answering doesn't have to write the entire thing if you already have parts done. People will be more likely to give you answers if you show the effort you've made already. At least post your code for the models involved and any user_controller code you have.

Comment: Sorry, I'm saying I have all my relations defined. But nothing for my users controller or users/show.hmtl.erb file. And I was only going to define the `show` method in my `users_controller` since that's the only view I'm going to invoke. @Beartech

Comment: what's the output of `@user.likes` and `@user.topics` ?

Comment: @joseramonc If I run it in the rails console, its errors, same goes for on my localhost.

Comment: You would need to run `@user = User.first` before running those so that @user is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your user_controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(user_params[:id])
end


def user_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:id)
end
```

In your show.html.erb:

```
<% @user.bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
  <%= bookmark.name %>  #guessing here as I don't know your DB schema
<% end %>

<% @user.likes.each do |like| %>
  <%= like.name %>   #still guessing
<% end %>
```

You said Bookmarks are nested in Topics, but you don't show that in your code. Instead of User model having:

```
has_many :bookmarks, dependent: :destroy
```

it should be

```
has_many :bookmarks, through: :topics, dependent: :destroy
```

You can still access bookmarks the same way:

```
@user.bookmarks
```